# How to invite friends to application with Facebook c# SDK 

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm developing a facebook connect Application with Facebook C# SDK, I want
to send application invites to my friend is it possible without using facebook
social plugins. What i mean is it possible only with codebehind?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In order to do anything through facebook, like invite friends, you have to use their api.

Comment: @xenon am I correct: you want to have your app post to someone else's wall? as far as I know, the only way to do that is to use dialogs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: Yes i want to do that with c#

Answer (score 2):

**invite facebook friend from your facebook application or website,use this small lines of code and send invitation to all facebook friends to visit your website.i also used this script its working nicely. 
your domain must be *ssl certified* because facebook not allowing unsecured domains.**

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
FB.init({
appId:'APP_ID',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog'
});
}
</script>


//HTML Code
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some code for that but can't send to my friends. Code is in the below

```
var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.appId = "{yourAPPid}";
parameters.message = "{yourmessage}";

dynamic id = fb.Post("me/apprequests", parameters);
```

[facebook sdk invite friends to application](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5909957/facebook-sdk-invite-friends-to-application)